# How to pass return url

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, url

I have 2 angular applications say app1 and app2

On every page of app1 , I have put a link to navigate to home page of app2.  So that user can go to home page of app2.

Now in home page of app2 I want to put a back link , on clicking of back link user should be able to go the exact same page in app1 from where he came here.

How to achieve this use case?.. basically what is the best way to open completely new page and pass a back URL(can be a long URL) to come back to the same page.

Thanks

Comment: Use `document.referrer` to retrieve the url the user came from. You can add a click listener somewhere and open the retrieved url in a new tab.

Comment: Thanks. Will try it

Comment: Its working but having one problem, the app1 is https and app2 is http, so in IE its not working. I did workaround by putting <meta name="referrer" content="unsafe-url"> for other browers. Any workaround for IE . Please suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are supposed to store the referral url.so you can store what ever the link you want.